# Como subir imagen a servidor node.js, usando expo-image-picker y typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, multer

Busco subir una imagen desde react native, usando la libreria expo-image-picker, a un servidor node.js que utiliza multer para procesar archivos. Una vez en el servidor, quiero subir la imagen a AWS.
He hecho este proceso completo con react web de forma exitosa. Sin embargo, con react native,
el archivo que recibo en el servidor (req.file) llega como undefined.

Este es el codigo que estoy usando:

```
//sendImage.tsx

import { useState } from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native'
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
const sendImage : React.FC = ()=>{
    
        const [picture, setPicture] = useState<string>('')
      
        const pickImage = async ():Promise<string|boolean> => {
          // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
          let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
          });
      
          console.log(result);
      
          if (!result.cancelled) {
            setPicture(result.uri);
            return result.uri
          }
          return false
        };

        const sendPictureToServer = async () => {
            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('file', picture)
            const result = await fetch(`http://localhost:5001/dashboard/chooseProfilePic`, {
                
                method : 'POST',
                body : formData
            })
            
        }
    return(
            <View>
                <Text>Change profile picture</Text>
                <Button title = 'select' onPress={pickImage}/>
                <Button title='send' onPress={sendPictureToServer}/>

            </View>
    )
}
```

Este es el lado del servidor

```
//
//  routes/dashboard.js
const {Router} = require('express')
const router = Router()
const multer= require('multer')
const upload= multer({dest:'uploads'})

router.post('/chooseProfilePic', upload.array('file') , controller.chooseProfilePicture)
```

```
// controller/dashboard.js
chooseProfilePicture : async(req, res) =>{
        const id = req.params.id
        console.log('this is the file',req.file) //imprime undefined

        const url = await bucket.uploadProfileImage(req.file, id)
        console.log(url)
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

tienes que agregar el Content-Type asi:

```
        const sendPictureToServer = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', picture)
        const result = await fetch(`http://localhost:5001/dashboard/chooseProfilePic`, {
            
            method : 'POST',
            body : formData,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
        })
        
    }
```

Comment: Agregar el encabezado que señalas usando fetch, produce el siguiente error en el servidor: "multipart boundary not found"Usando axios, no se produce tal error sin embargo, req.file sigue siendo undefined.